# How to extract something out of a JSON object and display it in the DOM

Tags: javascript

I keep getting undefined in the DOM...

I am trying to extract the city  and state from this and display it in the DOM.

```
{
 "post code": "90210", 
 "country": "United States", 
 "country abbreviation": "US", 
 "places": [
     {"place name": "Beverly Hills", 
      "longitude": "-118.4065", 
      "state": "California", 
      "state abbreviation": "CA", 
      "latitude": "34.0901"}
  ]
}
```

```
var data = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
                //var str = '';
                var boo = '';
                //str =  data[1];
                boo +=  data.state;
                //document.getElementById('city').innerText = str;
                document.getElementById('state').innerHTML = boo;
            } else { // Status error!
                //document.getElementById('city').innerHTML = ajax.statusText;
                document.getElementById('state').innerHTML = ajax.statusText;
            }
```

Comment: state is in the first object in the places array, so it would be `data.places[0].state`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that 'state' field is nested in another object which is nested inside of an array, so the correct way to access it would be

```
data.places[0].state
```